# Rack Gem::LoadError even though I'm using Bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, rack

I don't understand how this can happen:

```
$ bundle install
[...]
$ bundle exec rails server
[...] You have already activated rack 1.4.4, but your Gemfile requires rack 1.4.3. Using bundle exec may solve this. (Gem::LoadError)
```

I don't see how it's possible to have this error; doesn't Bundler protect against this?

```
$ gem list rack

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

rack (1.4.4, 1.4.3, 1.4.1)
```

In Gemfile, we needed to explicitly list rack for a UUID lib, I believe:

```
gem "rack"
```

Comment: Have you found any explanation?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to resolve this issue by simply uninstalling the version of rack I didn't want.

```
gem uninstall rack

Select gem to uninstall:
1. rack-1.4.1
2. rack-1.4.3
3. rack-1.4.4
4. All versions
> 3
Successfully uninstalled rack-1.4.4
```

Comment: Perfect! Worked for me too :)